# XSLT Key Grouping by considering multiple nodes based on a Condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping, xslkey

```
<root>
   <Entry>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>A1</Code>
         <Value>1000</Value>
         <Indicator>1</Indicator>
      </Details>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>A2</Code>
         <Value>2000</Value>
         <Indicator>2</Indicator>
      </Details>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>A3</Code>
         <Value>2500</Value>
         <Indicator>3</Indicator>
      </Details>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>B1</Code>
         <Value>3000</Value>
         <Indicator>0</Indicator>
      </Details>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>B2</Code>
         <Value>4000</Value>
         <Indicator>5</Indicator>
      </Details>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>6</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>B3</Code>
         <Value>4500</Value>
         <Indicator>7</Indicator>
      </Details>
   </Entry>
</root>
```

I have this input XML, which is a continuation to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321960/grouping-nodes-by-hardcoding-node-values-in-xslt). Basically I am looking to group the nodes based on the value of the `<Code>` node. The mapping is as follows:

1. Codes 'A1', 'A2' and 'A3' needs to be grouped together (lets say Code-group 'A')
2. Codes 'B1', 'B2' and 'B3' needs to be grouped together (lets say Code-group 'B')

[These codes are generic meant only as example and the actual codes are different and not so simple, please do not consider it literally]

I am eventually summing the values coming out of `<Value>` nodes in these groups but in addition to my previous question I am only summing if the `<Indicator>` node value is **greater than or equal to 2**

I currently use this XSLT (credits: michael.hor257k):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="entry" match="Entry" use="Details/Code"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Output>
        <Code-group> A </Code-group>
        <Sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('A1', 'A2', 'A3'))/Details/Value)" />
        </Sum>
        <Code-group> B </Code-group>
        <Sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('B1', 'B2', 'B3'))/Details/Value)" />
        </Sum>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces Output as follows:

```
<Output>
  <Code-group> A </Code-group>
  <Sum> 5500 </Sum>

  <Code-group> B </Code-group>
  <Sum> 11500 </Sum>
</Output>
```

But I need this Output for the scenario:

```
<Output>
  <Code-group> A </Code-group>
  <Sum> 4500 </Sum>

  <Code-group> B </Code-group>
  <Sum> 8500 </Sum>
</Output>
```

That is sum the `<Value>` node value in the respective Code-groups only when the `<Indicator>` is greater than or equal to `2`

Is there a way to include this relational operator while defining the Key or should it be realised as 2 keys? Appreciate any inputs

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you only need a small modification:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="entry" match="Details[Indicator >= 2]" use="Code"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Output>
        <Code-group> A </Code-group>
        <Sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('A1', 'A2', 'A3'))/Value)" />
        </Sum>
        <Code-group> B </Code-group>
        <Sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('B1', 'B2', 'B3'))/Value)" />
        </Sum>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use XPath predicates

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Output>
        <Code-group> A </Code-group>
        <Sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('A1', 'A2', 'A3'))/Details[Indicator >= 2 ]/Value)" />
        </Sum>
        <Code-group> B </Code-group>
        <Sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('B1', 'B2', 'B3'))/Details[Indicator >= 2 ]/Value)" />
        </Sum>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>
```