# XSLT Key Grouping for Child Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslkey, xsl-grouping

```
<root>
   <Entry>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>A1</Code>
         <Value>1000</Value>
      </Details>

      <Details>
         <Code>A2</Code>
         <Value>2000</Value>
      </Details>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Details>
         <Code>B1</Code>
         <Value>1500</Value>
      </Details>

      <Details>
         <Code>B2</Code>
         <Value>2500</Value>
      </Details>

      <Details>
         <Code>A3</Code>
         <Value>3000</Value>
      </Details>
   </Entry>

</root>
```

I have this Input XML. For each `<Entry>`, I am looking to group the `<Details>` nodes (which are the Child nodes of Entry) and eventually take the sum of the `<Value>` node values by following Code Groupings are as follows:

1. Codes A1, A2 and A3 should be grouped together (say 'A')
2. Codes B1, B2 and B3 should be grouped together (say 'B')

[Note: The Codes are just for example and the actual codes are entirely different, so a substring solution wont work, please do not consider these codes literally]

The Output would look like:

```
<Output>
    <Output-Line>
       <ID> 1 </ID>
      <Code-group> A </Code-group>
      <Sum> 3000 </Sum>

      <Code-group> B </Code-group>
      <Sum/>
    </Output-Line>

   <Output-Line>
       <ID> 2 </ID>
      <Code-group> A </Code-group>
      <Sum> 3000 </Sum>

      <Code-group> B </Code-group>
      <Sum> 4000 </Sum>
    </Output-Line>
</Output>
```

The problem that I am facing currently is that the `<xsl:key>` element should be declared at the top and not at individual Entry level in a for-each loop. Therefore I am not able to form a proper key with the match and use expression parameters. Any help appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is just another variation on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64321960/3016153), all you need to do is add another argument to the `key()` function call in order to restrict it to the current `Entry`:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="entry" match="Details" use="Code"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Entry">
            <Output-Line>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
                <Code-group> A </Code-group>
                <Sum>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('A1', 'A2', 'A3'), .)/Value)" />
                </Sum>
                <Code-group> B </Code-group>
                <Sum>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('entry', ('B1', 'B2', 'B3'), .)/Value)" />
                </Sum>
            </Output-Line>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes indeed, it was another variant of my previous questions, forgot to link them. Thanks again for the awesome answer, Michael. It's interesting to see how subtle modifications makes a lot of difference in XSLT codes. Thanks again!